# Magento email model encoding unfortunately defaults to iso-8859-1

Tags: email, magento, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'm sending an custom email in a magento shop. It's using a transactional template, which is fine. The problem is, that magento uses iso-8859-1 encoding for that custom email, indead of the default_encoding = 'utf-8' from Mage/Page/etc/config.xml

I've tried to look up for a function to set the encoding directly, but failed to find one. Did anyone encounter this problem and solved it?
I need it for a quick fix. I know I should better use the transactional mail system of magento, but we can't make major changes to the system, since it just went online and we don't have a running dev environment yet.

my code:

```
 public function customerSaveBefore($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

    //Array of customer data
    $customerData = $customer->getData();

    //email address from System > Configuration > Contacts
    $contactEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('contacts/email/recipient_email');

    //customer is new, otherwise it's an edit
    if (!$customer->getOrigData()) {


        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
        $addressData = $session->getCustomerAddress(); //get customers address from session variable

        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel("core/email_template")
            ->loadDefault("customer_notification");

        $emailTemplateVariables = array();
        $emailTemplateVariables["customer"] = $customer;
        $emailTemplateVariables["plz"] = $addressData['postcode'];
        $emailTemplateVariables["city"] = $addressData['city'];
        $emailTemplateVariables["company"] = $addressData['company'];
        $emailTemplateVariables["street"] = $addressData['street'][0];
        $emailTemplateVariables["phone"] = $addressData['telephone'];
        $emailTemplateVariables["erpid"] = $session->getCustomerUserId();

        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

        $mail = Mage::getModel("core/email")
        ->setToEmail("steinmille@gmail.com")
        ->setBody($processedTemplate)
        ->setFromEmail($sender)
        ->setFromName("EMAIL")
        ->setSubject("Subject")
        ->setType("html");

        try{
            $mail->send();
        }
        catch(Exception $error)
        {
            Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addError($error->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        $mail->setToEmail($recipient)
            ->setFromEmail($recipient);
        try{

        $session->setCustomerAddress([]); //clear customers address in session variable
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok, found the solution... Quickfix is to edit core or extend Core/Model/Email.php send function. There, change $mail = new Zend_Mail();  to $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');   which will set the encoding to utf-8 or get the default encoding from the store config

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to extend magento core:

in app/code/local/YOURTHEME/MODULE/Model/Email.php

```
class YOURTHEME_MODULE_Model_Email extends Mage_Core_Model_Email{
  public function send()
  {
    if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')) {
        return $this;
    }

    $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');

    if (strtolower($this->getType()) == 'html') {
        $mail->setBodyHtml($this->getBody());
    }
    else {
        $mail->setBodyText($this->getBody());
    }

    $mail->setFrom($this->getFromEmail(), $this->getFromName())
        ->addTo($this->getToEmail(), $this->getToName())
        ->setSubject($this->getSubject());
    $mail->send();

    return $this;
  }
}
```

and config.xml in app/code/local/YOURTHEME/MODULE/etc/config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <email>YOURTHEME_MODULE_Model_Email</email>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
    </models>
</global>
```